# Confused About Why Red Queen Hypothesis Wouldn't Apply to Deer's Color Vision

Tags: evolution, ecology, vision, predation, color

In this site,https://www.livescience.com/why-are-tigers-orange, it says ""But there seems to be no evolutionary pressure, particularly for deer, which are the main prey of the tiger, to become trichromatic. That's probably because the tiger doesn't know it's orange either because it, too, is a dichromat."

I am assuming the "evolutionary pressure" refers to the Red Queen Hypothesis. But then why would it matter if the tiger doesn't know its own color? Because it is hiding in the brush anyways, so wouldn't deer who can see red have an advantage over deer who couldn't?

Thank you

Comment: "*That's probably because the tiger doesn't know it's orange either because it, too, is a dichromat.*" That phrase right there is garbage. You don't need to know your own weaknesses for someone else to exploit them nor do you need to know why something works for it to work.

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE. Please take the [tour] and then go through the [help] pages starting with [Ask] questions effectively on this site. In general, we expect you to do some research on your own and then, informed by what you have learned, ask any questions you still have (ideally with references to reliable sources). In particular, this question demonstrates the value of consulting multiple sources — the quoted statement is as you guessed nonsense. [You may find this introduction to evolutionary theory from UC Berkeley useful](https://evolution.berkeley.edu/evolibrary/article/evo_01).

Comment: @tyersome That was helpful indeed! Thanks! Also, could you explain how you got the link to the stack exchange link? Was it through a search engine query, saw-the-link before, etc.? Thank you

Comment: You're welcome. This type of question comes up quite often, which is why that post was created and why I was already aware that it existed. Due to it being a very general answer it isn't that easy to find when you have specific question like yours in mind, so don't feel bad about not finding it yourself.

Comment: what makes you think orange is bad camouflage. in many many environments orange is very good camouflage, no color pattern is good in every environment.